# border image repeat from pixel

Tags: html, css

hello I want to know if there's a way that I can make a border from an image which is 1px but repeat and the border width is 13px.

to get an output like this

[image: 1 pixel border repeated]

Thank you

Comment: Simply `border: 13px solid rgba(...);`

Comment: The border is 1px AND 13px wide? How should that work?

Comment: Have you Googled this at all??? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: @feeela It's my understanding that the OP wants to produce a 13px border using a 1px x 1px image.

Comment: @feela 1 pixel that has the color and 13px the width and fill it as if i m dealing with a div

Comment: What is the requirement of it being a 1px wide image? You will not gain any real benefit from using a 1px by 1px image vs a 13px by 13px image.

Comment: @MFarahat Are you aware of `rgba()`? It is supported in modern browsers and is possibly more appropriate for what you want.

Comment: @feeela The 1px the OP is referring to is the semi-transparent image that they wish to have repeated along the 13px border.

Comment: @philtune it doesn't work with 1pixel image

Comment: Ah, OK. Couldn't imagine where to use an image here. @MFarahat You only need images for a border if this border is NOT in a single color (and a transparent color still is just one color). There are some border-image examples in the live demo on the article [Understanding border-image](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/). In your case an rgba border (as mentioned earlier) should work.

Comment: @MFarahat @philtune is saying you don't need to use an image, use `rgba()` instead. The `a` in rgba is the alpha channel which will give you control over the amount of opacity/transparency of the border.

Comment: @George I cant use colors as #d5b380 because its not the same on every browser/operating system

Comment: @MFarahat “its not the same on every…” The same holds true for colors in an image. You can't achieve color consistency without calibrating the screens of all users first.

Comment: @MFarahat I think you're focusing on the wrong things here. You'll never get the exact color you want to display as every monitor is different and each user might adjust the color settings to their liking.

Comment: @hungerstar the benefit of making this by only 1 pixel is that i ll be able to resize the border without resizing the image and of not having lots of images

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in 2 ways.

**1.**

Since you only have a 1px image with (obviously) 1 color, `rgba()` may be more appropriate here:

```
border: 13px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* use your colorcode */
```

**2.**

```
div { /* this is your div with the content in it */
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

div:before { /* this will be your "border", it will be placed underneath your "content" div */
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    left: -13px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 13px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(your-border-image.png);
}
```

Comment: I made it border color because the other one is not working right

Answer (score 0):

Put the image inside a div like this:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="myimage.png" />
</div>
```

Then add the border to that div:

```
.image {

    border: 13px solid rgba(220, 190, 148, 0.3);

}
```

Voila!

Comment: Where do you got that idea from, that there is an image somewhere? And if there is, why don't you set the border to that image?

Comment: If you set the border to the div, other images can use the CSS of that div, I know you can add it to the image but it's cleaner to do it inside the div.

Comment: @Azael Just a thought: how is adding a container element *cleaner* than not doing so?

Comment: Where else are you gonna put your image?, just floating nowhere? Most elements need to be put inside a div for better design, development, and to better manage your code, which will lead to a happier life :)

Comment: @Azael If you put most of your elements into DIV's just for styling purposes you are doing something wrong. In fact you should start off with the markup and afterwards style the elements that are available. A good demonstration to do so is the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/), which presents very different design – but always uses the same markup. Form follows function. Not the other way around.

Comment: *'Most elements need to be put inside a div'* - Is that so? Can you support this claim? (:

Comment: Yes, take my word for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rgba` colors for the background and border to create such an effect:

```
background: rgba(234,198,152,.8);
border: 13px solid rgba(162,130,89,.5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/c4ca46yo/

You can expand that example and load the correct fonts through @font-face and just include the background image and the stones as real images. (using an IMG-tag or CSS background-image)